# Asp.net jquery call to Page Method is not finding to HelloWorld

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, pagemethods

I'm trying to run a basic test to get Hello World running from the WebService.asmx page but I found out through debugging that its not even reaching the page method in the WebService.asmx page.  I been working for about an entire day on this and I would greatly appreciate your help.  Here's my code.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string HelloWorld() 
{
    return "Hello World";
}

function test() {

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "EmployeesWebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: "{}",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: OnFailure,
        error: OnError
        });

    }
```

I've tried many variations of this and I keep getting an error.  I also have [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] uncommented.

Also heres my web.config

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Scheduling.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
            <httpModules>
                 <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            </httpModules>

         </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the parentheses, and you should put a result format as well. Change the method attributes to this...

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod()]
```